# How to convert hexadecimal word to signed integer in python 2-7?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to write a method for converting hexadecimal words to signed integers. I want to use python 2-7. In python3 I can do the following

```
def word2int(hex_str):
    ba = bytes.fromhex(hex_str)
    return int.from_bytes(ba,byteorder='big',signed=True)
```

However, neither of these methods (i.e. fromhex and from_bytes) are defined in python 2-7. Are there any nice and simple methods of doing this in Python 2-7?

Comment: Have you tried the `struct` module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `int` to convert to an unsigned integer, and then manually convert to signed.

```
def word_to_int(hex_str):
    value = int(hex_str, 16)
    if value > 127:
        value = value-256
    return value
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that! Seems to work for 16-bit strings as well, only with -65534 instead of -256.